# I am getting parse error when using swiftmailer to send email

Tags: php, mailer

I am trying to do:

```
        \Yii::$app->mailer->htmlLayout = "layouts/html";
        \Yii::$app->mailer->compose("mail", [
            'customername' => $customername,
            'email_greeting' => $email_greeting,
            'invoicenumber' => $invoicenumber,
            'totalbill' => $totalbill,
            'duedate' => $duedate,
            'invoiceurl' => $invoiceurl,
            'email_notes' => $email_notes,
            'email_logo' =>$email_logo])
            ->setFrom($merchant_email)
            ->setTo("myemail@gmail.com") 
            ->setSubject($email_subject)
            ->setHtmlBody($htmlContent)
            ->send();
```

But I keep getting error:

```
{
    "name": "PHP Parse Error",
    "message": "syntax error, unexpected '?'",
    "code": 4,
    "type": "yii\\base\\ErrorException",
    "file": "/var/www/html/app/billingbackendapi/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Mime/SimpleMessage.php",
    "line": 490,
    "stack-trace": [
        "#0 [internal function]: yii\\base\\ErrorHandler->handleFatalError()",
        "#1 {main}"
    ]
}
```

I do not understand what I did wrong on my part.
I see certain examples this is what my code should like.

Comment: The error is in the swiftmailer package itself. I think it has to do with what version of PHP you are running. I found a similar error on their github page: https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/issues/1057 your best bet is to either upgrade your PHP to 7 or use an older version of swiftmailer.